# Grails 2.4.3: Managing a changing schema

Tags: database, grails, schema, auto-generate

I'm trying to develop a system which accesses a schema which is managed and updated by another system, so the database schema is likely to change independently of my system. It's unlikely to be new tables or dropping columns, more the adding of new columns.

Is there a way I can auto update my domain classes whenever a column is added to the schema, ideally via calling a web service and then this web service update the domain classes? Even if it's one CLI command it would be better than having to make manual code changes. I know that you can auto-scaffold (build views and controllers) but is there anyway to examine a schema and look for new columns and then add the new properties to a domain class?

I've taken a look at various plugins and pages, including [db-reverse-engineer](http://www.grails.org/plugin/db-reverse-engineer) (not compatible with 2.4.3),  [database-migration](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration) (seems to more be for updating a database after domain class changes) and [dynamic-domain-class](http://grails.org/plugin/dynamic-domain-class) (seems to create whole new domain classes rather than just update properties).

At the moment, the only way I can think of doing this is to run some custom sql to examine the schema myself, pull back column names, types and constraints and then use the dynamic-domain-class plugin to make my own domain classes on the fly. But this seems messy.

I want to essentially, know about the domain class names but have a system which is domain class property agnostic, so that I can dynamically build a gui based on the properties of the domain classes (auto-scaffold) at runtime.

Thanks for any ideas / pointers in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Dude ,just barely think. place some code who can monitor you the changes on the remote side , for sure that you have that record o stored or send to your grails application at some point of time that is stable or some sort of time. You could use like to monitor the remote database and generate a report of change logs from the remote and then may be try to write a script

1.To update your domain models accordingly for example if lastname field added on Customers Table

2.Then the good advise i can give is to dynamically execute change log script after you have made changes into your domain using some sort script , database snapshots or some sort of synchronization to better work with AUTOSCAFFOLDING.

Just an Idea . . .

Comment: It's another approach. I don't really have access to the remote side per se, only a database connection but I could write a custom script that can be run to generate the change log and then run the database migration script. I was just hoping for a programmatic way of doing it, rather than by command line. It's way more testable. And I'm a dudette ;)

Comment: You'll find that you get more upvotes and accepted answers if you avoid insulting phrases like "just barely think". Similarly, avoid YELLING AT PEOPLE WITH ALL CAPS. I didn't ask this question, but as soon as I saw "Dude" I immediately assumed that this would be a low quality answer. Insult people less and they'll take you seriously.

Answer (score 0):

Just about the reverse engineering plugin, you can still run it with grails 2.4.3. The problem is the dependency to Hibernate 4, since the Hibernate API changed.

If you want to keep on using this plugin, you can come back to Hibernate 3, by commenting the following line:

```
runtime ":hibernate4:4.X.X.X"
```

and by adding this one instead:

```
runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.17"
```

Then it will run perfectly. I'm still planning on upgrading this very useful plugin... but it will take a while :/

Comment: I tried to do this but then I got a whole bunch of errors due to interdependencies with other plugins (mainly my Oracle SQL dataSource setup I think). I might try again.

Comment: It's a weird plugin, because it's not one where it is always active like a security plugin, or resources, etc. Typically you run it a few times and you're done. So after that there's little reason to keep in installed. If it doesn't work in the version of Grails you're using, install it in a version where it does work and use that app to do the reverse engineering work. Copy the generated code into your real app and enjoy the rest of your day.

Comment: I get that use case. I wanted to ideally be able to call it programmatically on-the-fly rather than having to rely on manual intervention every time the schema changes slightly.